# Equivalent resistance of a circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, electrical-engineering

Can anyone help me with this one please?! I want to find the total resistance but the circuit seems neither parallel nor serie. What should I do?! [image]

Comment: Hi welcome to the forum. Please have a look to the policy of the forum, here we do not solve exercises..

Comment: Hi Amine and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you need the total current $I_{tot}$ and the applied voltage $V$.  Moreover, you want $I_1\ldots I_5$ and $U_1\ldots U_5$. That makes in total 12 unknown quantities, so you need 12 equations.

You get 5 equations from $U_j=R_j I_j$, so 7 more to go.  These follow from Kirchhoffs laws:  I see three loops and 4 junctions, which gives you 7 equations, e.g. $V=U_2+U_4$ and $I_{tot}=I_1+I_2$.

Good luck.